# Mobile menu not opening on click...

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I tried recreating the issue in a jsFiddle, but wasn't able to.

There's a link to my site **[here](http://webfro.gs/south/tour3579/)**...

It's a responsive site, but the menu isn't working and I can't figure out why. Wondering if someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

**Here's the script for the menu...**

```
$(function() {

    var mobileMenu  = $('.mobile-menu');
        menu        = $('#menu ul');
        menuHeight  = menu.height();

    $(mobileMenu).on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 760 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });

});
```

I've gone through everything I know of and double-checked my work. The menu simply won't open when clicked on.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

layout.css, line 599, try changing `display: none;` to `display: block;`:

```
#menu {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

To hide the menu onclick, you could try something like this:

```
$('#menu a').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $('#menu').slideUp();
    };
});
```

You could also use `$('#menu').hide();` if you dislike the animation.

Comment: 9 minutes left to accept. I must have inadvertently changed that somewhere along the way. Thanks Stuart! Keep coding my friend.

Comment: When I open the menu from a mobile device, it stays open unless the icon is clicked again. Do you know if there's a fix for that, or is that a normal behavior?

Comment: I see what you mean... You could attach an event to the dropdown click to hide the <ul>. I assume the dropdown might not have been built for this style of site, but that update shouldn't be too complex. I'll add a snip of code for you to try in answer above.